# Why is a single function not called second time in a jquery handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create two divs that respond on mouseclick while increasing or decreasing their saturations. Here is a short fiddle to my problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/ds6w5uwj/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var oldbgc;
  oldbgc = void 0;
  return $(document.body).on('click', '.prio-step', function() {
    var bg, newbgc;
    alert("color recalc started");
    bg = $(this).css('background-color');
    oldbgc = rgb2hex(bg); //This line is only executed in the very first run
    newbgc = applySaturationToHexColor(oldbgc, 30);
    return $(this).css({
      backgroundColor: newbgc
    });
  });
});
```

When you click on one div the first time, rgb2hex(bg) is called and the right value is written to oldbgc. But when you try to click again no matter on which div you want the script skips that specific line leading to NaN error.
I found both functions, `applySaturationToHexColor(...)` and `rgb2hex(...)`, as top answers to their corresponding questions here on stackoverflow.com.

Comment: `console.log(bg)`

Comment: Why void 0? you could use undefined, null, 0 or any other value...

Comment: Thanks, @Jonasw, but unfortunately, it makes no difference to my problem ...:(

Comment: @epascarello, thanks for the tip, I am gonna use it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code I see scope issues.

You have something on these lines in your code.

```
rgb2hex= function(rgb_in) { <============= #1
    // removed for simplicity
};

applySaturationToHexColor= function(hex, saturationPercent) {
    // removed for simplicity
    rgb2hex = function(rgb) { <============= #2
      return '#' + floatToHex(rgb[0]) + floatToHex(rgb[1]) + floatToHex(rgb[2]);
    };
    newHex = rgb2hex(newRgbIntensityFloat); <============= #3
    return newHex;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    // removed for simplicity
    $(document.body).on('click', '.prio-step', function() {
       oldbgc = rgb2hex(bg); <============= #4
    });
    // removed for simplicity
  });
});
```

Carefully check the lines I have pointed as 1,2,3 and 4. You have defined rgb2hex twice, once at pointer #1 and second at pointer #2. So when inside your on-click event when you intend to call function defined at pointer #1 your code ends up calling function at pointer #2 instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for your anwer! This kind of mistake occurs if you don't check the code that you copy and pasted... :D

Renaming `rgb2hex()` to `rgb2_hex()` and changing the function call in line #4 solved my problem.

Comment: Hehe.. Happens all the time. You should consider using TypeScript, just a suggestion :)